# Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No certificates for user server were found for encryption

Tags: java, web-services, ws-security

I am developing soap security web services in Wildfly 10 with this ref site.

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/WS-Security?_sscc=t

Until Wildfly 8, `org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback` class is involved in wss4j-x.x.x.jar of wildfly 8 modules as you know. However from Wildfly 10 I can't find wss4j-x.x.x.jar. But I imported `wss4j-ws-security-common-2.1.4.jar` which contains `org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSPasswordCallback`. And deployment is ok.

The problem is client codes with encryption. This is the code:

```
((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, new KeystorePasswordCallback());
 ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_PROPERTIES, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/client.properties"));
 ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_PROPERTIES, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("META-INF/client.properties"));
 ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.SIGNATURE_USERNAME, "client");
 ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(SecurityConstants.ENCRYPT_USERNAME, "server");

out.println(port.sayHello("jina")); // This line throws the following exceptions.
```

These are exception :

```
19:43:50,789 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-12) Interceptor for {http://soap.aaa.com/}HelloWorldService#{http://soap.aaa.com/}sayHello has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No certificates for user server were found for encryption
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:391)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.handleBinding(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:126)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessageInternal(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:187)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:109)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor$PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptorInternal.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JOutInterceptor.java:96)
 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
 at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy97.sayHello(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:144)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:402)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:346)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
 at io.undertow.jsp.JspFileHandler.handleRequest(JspFileHandler.java:32)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
 at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
 at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
 at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
 at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
 at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
 at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
 at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: No certificates for user server were found for encryption
 at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecEncryptedKey.prepare(WSSecEncryptedKey.java:217)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.AbstractBindingBuilder.getEncryptedKeyBuilder(AbstractBindingBuilder.java:1433)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.setupEncryptedKey(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:888)
 at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.policyhandlers.SymmetricBindingHandler.doSignBeforeEncrypt(SymmetricBindingHandler.java:288)
 ... 47 more

19:43:50,789 ERROR [stderr] (default task-12) javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: No certificates for user server were found for encryption
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states the problem quite clearly "No certificates for user server were found for encryption".
Be sure to have a public key with the alias "server" in the keystore referenced in your client.properties